# couchbase bucket select

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-bucket

I want to select a certain bucket in a couchbase telnet session.
F.e. I can get value from the default bucket with this command:
get a1 0

How to select a bucket through couchbase memcached protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you created a bucket that has a password the you must use a client that supports sasl authentication in order to access the bucket. Couchbase uses plain sasl authentication and the username is the bucket name and the password is the password that you specified for the bucket. If you create a bucket without a password then it is required to be on a different port. For the passwordless type of bucket you just need to specify the port that the bucket is listening on to telnet.